# Extract columns from two different database in sqlite3

Tags: sql, sqlite

Is it possible to extract columns from two different database in sqlite3?

My problem is, I have two tables in two different database and I want to retrieve columns from tables from these two database.

To make it more clear, here is my pseudocode.

```
"SELECT Table_FromFirstDatabase.product 
 FROM MyFirstDatabase.Table_FromFirstDatabase
 WHERE   product NOT IN ('SELECT  Table_FromSecondDatabase.product 
                        FROM MySecondDatabase.Table_FromSecondDatabase');"
```

Is it possible to do something like this in sqlite3 ??

Thank you....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that:

[ATTACH](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_attach.html) statements in SQLite.

Note that you could probably use `SELECT t1.product FROM db1.tbl1 AS t1 EXCEPT (other select statement)` instead of `WHERE NOT IN`

Answer (score 0):

No. It's probably better for you to pull the data in a local list/array anyways.